# Is it possible to get github wiki content by github api

Tags: api, github, wiki

Checked  https://developer.github.com/v3/

I can't find out any api which can get github wiki content?

Comment: could you figure out if it's possible or not @Daniel

Comment: I think there is no way to use Github rest API for Wiki repos :(

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to use the `wiki` as a separate Git repository by specifying this in the url: `https://github.com/user/project.wiki.git`

See more [here](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis)

Comment: Unfortunately, only contributors have push access.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to treat the wiki repository the same way like regular repositories for the API: https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo.wiki will return a 404.