# How to read github wiki pages from the JS API?

Tags: javascript, git, github

Its definitely possibly via [command-line git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654854/is-it-possible-to-get-github-wiki-content-by-github-api), and reading repo files from a branch is definitely possibly via the [JS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560720/how-to-initialize-the-github-api-with-an-api-token/37560933#37560933), however, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to read wiki pages. I'm using the [gh3.js](https://github.com/k33g/gh3) wrapper and this [sample code to read a file](https://github.com/k33g/gh3/blob/master/samples/05-file.html) as a basis for my script.

So far I figured out that the wiki is not a branch of the main repo. It might be a repo or something else. I'm trying to read this [sample wiki page](https://github.com/rhino/rhino.github.io/wiki/TestPage).

Answer (score 0):

the wiki is in a separate repository:

```
https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git
```

see https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/

Comment: Try it out online - visit https://api.github.com/repos/rhino/rhino.github.io then visit https://api.github.com/repos/rhino/rhino.github.io.wiki